# Prove that if $A$ is diagonally dominant and if $Q$ is chosen as in the Jacobi method, then $\rho(I-Q^{-1}A)<1$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

**Prove that if $A$ is diagonally dominant and if $Q$ is chosen as in the Jacobi method, then $\rho(I-Q^{-1}A)<1$**

I know that $\rho(A)=\inf_{\|.\|}\|A\|$ and \begin{equation}                                                                                                                                                            
||I-Q^{-1}A||_\infty = \max_{1\leq i\leq n}\sum\limits_{j=1,j\neq i}^n \left|\frac{a_{ij}}{a_{ii}}\right|                                                                   
\end{equation}, but I do not know what else I can do to show what I want, could someone help me please?

Comment: Perhaps, $Q = \textrm{diag}\left(a_{11}, \cdots, a_{nn} \right)$, where $a_{ii}$ are the diagonal elements of $A$!?

Answer (score 1):

This property can be easily shown with the help of this [property of the spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Power_sequence): For the spectral radius the following holds for any matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n} $ and any (matrix) norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$:
$$\rho(A) \leq \Vert A \Vert. $$

Thus, for your chosen norm and a [*strictly* diagonally dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix) matrix $A$ you get [convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method#Convergence) since $$\sum\limits_{j=1,j\neq i}^n \left|\frac{a_{ij}}{a_{ii}}\right| < 1 \: \forall \: i$$ and thus $$\rho \big(I-Q^{-1}A\big) \leq \big\Vert I-Q^{-1}A \big\Vert_\infty < 1 \checkmark$$